# How to login Google account from asp.net core web API(5.0) without navigate to Google sign-in page and which returns the token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

can anyone help me by writing the google login api without navigate to google page and credentials should be validate in that api only and need to generate the token if that credentials are valid

Comment: Dude this is not a site to get homework done. You will have to take some efforts on your own. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: how will you validate credentials which are not with your API ? if you want to validate the credentials in your API the why do need google account.

Comment: This sounds like a major security breach. They would have to provide the google credentials directly to your application. You could steal the credentials.

Redirecting the users to google itself to authenticatie is the way to go to ensure a secure setup

Comment: I mean if there is a google account with those credentials then only it should return token